# Bind view added at runtime with Data in MVVM

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, mvvm, android-mvvm

Adding run time view so how I can add that view data in MVVM.

Here is the code

```
FragmentHomeBinding fragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    FragmentHomeViewModel fragmentHomeViewModel = new FragmentHomeViewModel(getActivity());
    fragmentHomeBinding.setViewModel(fragmentHomeViewModel);
    /*Adding Dynamic View At run time.*/
    View dynamicToFromView = getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.dynamic_from_to, fragmentHomeBinding.llDynamicLayoutContainer, false);
    fragmentHomeBinding.llDynamicLayoutContainer.addView(dynamicToFromView);
```

`R.layout.dynamic_from_to` is the view which needed to be added to data at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily archive it by below code,

```
DynamicFromToBinding dynamicFromToBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.dynamic_from_to, fragmentHomeBinding.llDynamicLayoutContainer, false);
dynamicFromToBinding.setData(data)
View dynamicToFromView = dynamicFromToBinding.getRoot();
fragmentHomeBinding.llDynamicLayoutContainer.addView(dynamicToFromView);
```

Simply make your view data binding compatible and you can set data, handlers and all.